# schemaless insert in TDengine using jdbc connector

Tags: tdengine

I tried to do a schemaless insert by using TDengine JDBC connector, but got following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: TDengine ERROR (2350): failed to insertLines
        at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBError.createSQLException(TSDBError.java:76)
        at com.taosdata.jdbc.TSDBJNIConnector.insertLines(TSDBJNIConnector.java:366)
        at com.taosdata.jdbc.SchemalessWriter.write(SchemalessWriter.java:35)
        at com.taosdata.jdbc.SchemalessInsertTest.schemalessInsert(SchemalessInsertTest.java:39)
```

my code is as follows

```java
String[] lines = new String[]{
                "stb,t1=35 json_test=L\"{\"carNumber\":\"\",\"image\":\"\",\"outParkingSpace\":1638927251000,\"parkingSpaceStatus\":0}\" 1645329601000000000"};
        // when
        SchemalessWriter writer = new SchemalessWriter(conn);
        writer.write(lines, SchemalessProtocolType.LINE, SchemalessTimestampType.NANO_SECONDS);

        // then
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("show tables");
```

but the code works if I remove

> "carNumber":"","image":"",

in json_test, any idea why I got this error?

Answer (score 1):

works to me with version 2.4.0.12, you can try it.